# How to use a column for a shaded area in ggplot,R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataframe of 2 columns, my `values` and the `standard error`.
What I want is to plot a line with my values and then add the standard error as a shaded area around my line. 
I do not even know how to start as most of the [examples](https://rpubs.com/chidungkt/408264) use the `geom_ribbon` and not an existing column.

I am really confused, is it even possible to plot a shaded area based on an existing column? (any suggestions of tutorials or demos are welcomed!)

Comment: Please supply some sample data and show what you've tried so far. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some details on how to ask a good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need 3 columns, timestamp, value and std. And it's as simple as use your std column inside the aes(ymin, ymax):

```
library(tidyverse)
huron <- data.frame(year = 1875:1972, 
                value = LakeHuron,
                std = runif(length(LakeHuron),0,1))

huron %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, value)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = value - std, ymax = value + std), fill = "steelblue2") + 
  geom_line(color = "firebrick", size = 1)
```

In case you want to group your data, you should use fill = your_group and group = your_group inside the aes:

```
library(tidyverse)
huron <- data.frame(year = rep(1875:1972,2), 
                group = c(rep("a",98),rep("b",98)),
                value = c(LakeHuron, LakeHuron + 5),
                std = runif(length(LakeHuron)*2,0,1))

huron %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, value, fill = group, group=group)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = value - std, ymax = value + std), fill = 
  "steelblue2") + 
  geom_line(color = "firebrick", size = 1)
```

I posted this tip here: https://typethepipe.com/vizs-and-tips/ggplot_geom_ribbon_shadow/ for more info. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Carlos! That worked!Just a question, for cases when we have grouped lines, do we have to add separate geom_ribbons?

Comment: Glad to help! This is a good question, i edited the answer! :) Let me know if it solves your question

Comment: Nice post! I focus so much on the analysis of data and so I find myself struggling with the creation of beautiful plots, quite often! Thanks again!. You may also add the inclusion of different linetypes in your post! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

In this example the `se` column is your standard errors for the values:

```
require(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)

n_obs <- 50
my_data <- tibble(
  values = rnorm(n_obs),
  se = rbinom(n_obs, 5, .5)
)


my_data %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(1:n_obs, values), color = 'red') +
  geom_ribbon(aes(1:n_obs,
                  ymin = values - se,
                  ymax = values + se),
                  alpha = 1/5,
                  fill = 'steelblue')
```

[image: some line chart with +-1SE]